# Find difference between two arrays in Lua

Tags: loops, lua

Let's say I have two arrays

```
a = { "apple", "pear", "orange", "pineapple", "tomato" }
b = { "kiwi", "strawberry", "melon" }
```

How can I compare the two arrays, and detect the entries in array `b` which aren't in array `a`?

Comment: You need to specify more rules about that comparison, e.g., 'what if "pear" at the key 2 isn't "pear"? ...', etc... Do you want to know if "pear" was also removed, for instance?

Comment: array `a` will always be the same. array `b` will be updating regularly, I  just need to know the values in `b` which aren't in `a`, order doesn't matter. I have updated the wording of the question

Comment: The smart approach is simply use a dictionary for A, iterate over B, and do a lookup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how I do it: for each <s>key</s> (oops, meant value) in table `b`, I check if each doesn't exist in table `a`, just like a filter.

```
-- Filter table #1.
-- @return A table.
function table:filter(filterFnc)
    local result = {};

    for k, v in ipairs(self) do
        if filterFnc(v, k, self) then
            table.insert(result, v);
        end
    end

    return result;
end

-- Get index of a value at a table.
-- @param any value
-- @return any
function table:find(value)
    for k, v in ipairs(self) do
        if v == value then
            return k;
        end
    end
end

a = { "apple", "pear", "orange", "pineapple", "tomato" };
b = { "kiwi", "strawberry", "melon" };

local additions;

-- filter b to check additions
additions = table.filter(b, function(value)
    return not table.find(a, value);
end);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this code:

```
A = {}
for k,v in pairs(a) do
        A[v]=true
end

for k,v in pairs(b) do
        if A[v]==nil then print(v,"not in a") end
end
```

If `a` does not change, you need to build `A` only once.

All this would be easier if you used *sets* instead of *lists*. The first loop builds the set of values in the list `a`.

Or you can write them as sets in the first place:

```
a = { ["apple"]=true, ["pear"]=true, ["orange"]=true, ["pineapple"]=true, ["tomato"]=true }   
b = { ["kiwi"]=true, ["strawberry"]=true, ["melon"]=true}
```

With sets, you don't need any loops: if `k` contains a string you want to test, then `a` has `k` iff `a[k]==true`.